# Issue in deploying azure function through terraform with app settings

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-functions, terraform-provider-azure

I am Following this docs page to deploy azure function with app settings https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/function_app

My terraform file looks like :

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "3.10.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
}
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "azure-functions-test-rg"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "funcdemo123shafiq"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "example" {
  name                = "azure-functions-test-service-plan"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  sku {
    tier = "Standard"
    size = "S1"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_function_app" "example" {
  name                       = "test-azure-shafiq123"
  location                   = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name        = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  app_service_plan_id        = azurerm_app_service_plan.example.id
  storage_account_name       = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
  storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_access_key
  os_type                    = "linux"
  version                    = "~4"

  app_settings {
    FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME = "python"
    TESTING_KEY              = "TESTING_VALUE"
  }

  site_config {
    linux_fx_version = "python|3.9"
  }
}
```

When try to deploy this through `terraform apply` command , I am getting this error.

```
│ Error: Unsupported block type
│
│   on main.tf line 46, in resource "azurerm_function_app" "example":
│   46:   app_settings {
│
│ Blocks of type "app_settings" are not expected here. Did you mean to define argument "app_settings"? If so, use the equals sign to assign it a value.
```

Comment: What is unclear to you about the error message?

Comment: It is not about the error message, according to the docs we can set up the app setting but it is giving an error and it doesn't make sense, I have just copy-pasted what they got in the docs but it is giving an error.

@mkrieger1 did you get a chance to check the docs link I posted?

Comment: The error message does literally state the issue in the config code, and the config code in the question is not copied and pasted from the doc. The doc agrees with the error message.

Comment: so then what I am doing wrong and how can I fix it, I just need to create an azure function app with pre-defined app settings?

Comment: Argument is different compared to a block. That's what the error says. https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/function_app#app_settings

Comment: Hey, I did reproduce this issue and the solution worked for me; do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot. [Help Center - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`app_setting` is supported on specific version of Terraform AzureRM provider. There is [***bug fixed***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/terraform/provider-version-history-azurerm) availble for those version. I have used `3.3.0` provider version and it is working for me as expected and also you can't configure the value of `site_config`.Its value will be decide automatically based on the result of applying this configuration, same you can check in the updated **[document](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/linux_function_app#example-usage)** of Terraform

**main.tf**

```
 terraform {
      required_providers {
        azurerm = {
          source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
          version = "3.3.0"
        }
      }
    }
    
    provider "azurerm" {
        features{}
    }
    data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
      name     = "v-rXXXXXree"
      #location = "West Europe"
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
      name                     = "funcdemo123shafiq4535"
      resource_group_name      = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      location                 = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
      account_tier             = "Standard"
      account_replication_type = "LRS"
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_service_plan" "example" {
      name                = "azure-functions-test-service-plan1"
      location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
      resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      os_type             = "Linux"
      sku_name            = "Y1"
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "example" {
      name                       = "test-azure-shafi4353"
      location                   = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
      resource_group_name        = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      service_plan_id            =  azurerm_service_plan.example.id
      storage_account_name       = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
      storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_access_key
      #os_type                    = "linux"
      #version                    = "~3"
    
      app_settings={
        FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME = "python"
        TESTING_KEY              = "TESTING_VALUE"
      }
    
      site_config {
        #linux_fx_version = "python|3.9"
      }
    
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you check after deployment of these app settings in the azure function configuration in azure?

Comment: Updated the answer with correct solution. Now you can check it will work for you. Sorry for the missing few update in previous answer